# FIle not found while Loading Image.FromFile from controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Controller, which is accessing Image from the file Which is in another folder. 
I tried every possible path, But failed. :(

Here is my directory folder

```
/Controller
/Controller/ImagesController.cs
/ImageDB
/ImageDB/google.png
```

I tried it accessing it many ways, few are here

```
Image objImage = Image.FromFile("~/ImageDB/google.png");
Image objImage = Image.FromFile("../ImageDB/google.png");
```

And also can you please explain the use of ~ in the paths in @uri 
 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the file is actually added to your project and not just sitting in your file system.

Try using

```
Image objImage = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("/ImageDB/google.png"));
```

~ is used to denote the root of your website, so that no matter what folder/file your code is executing under, you can give a determinate location of another file..

e.g. "~/Static/site.css" rather than worrying about "../../Static/site.css" or "../../../Static/site.css" etc.